# Run a certain line of code for each user on windows pc/

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subinacl

For the script:

```
@echo off
title Applying Noah service rights, please wait...
cd c:/subinacl
subinacl /service NoahServer /grant=%Computername%\user=TOP
subinacl /service NoahClient /grant=%Computername%\user=TOP
pause
```

This script grants using Subinacl users administrative rights over certain services. However as you can see this is only for one user named(user) on the computer %Computername%.

I was wondering if there is a possibility to run the 2 lines starting with Subinacl for all users on the local computer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WMIC` to get a list of user names defined on the computer, and then use `FOR` to iterate over each one.  The code sample below should get you started.

Be warned that the below does not attempt to filter out built-in or other "special" accounts.  I am also unsure of quoting syntax as applies to `SUBINACL`.  I suggest you review it for desired behavior before removing the `ECHO` lines in front of the `SUBINACL` calls.

```
@echo off
title Applying Noah service rights, please wait...
cd c:/subinacl
FOR /F "usebackq" %%a IN (`WMIC UserAccount GET Name`) DO CALL :process_account "%%a"
pause
REM exit batch script file
EXIT /B

:process_account
SETLOCAL
REM strip any quotes from argument
SET ACCT=%~1
REM skip blank names
IF "%ACCT%"=="" EXIT /B
REM skip "Name" header from WMIC
IF "%ACCT%"=="Name" EXIT /B
ECHO Processing account: %1
REM remove the ECHO in front of SUBINACL once tested
ECHO subinacl /service NoahServer /grant="%Computername%\%ACCT%"=TOP
ECHO subinacl /service NoahClient /grant="%Computername%\%ACCT%"=TOP
REM return to CALLer
EXIT /B
```

Comment: I will try this out asap. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Hi outstanding! This worked just as i was visualizing it.